# Issue with Snap svg animating when it shouldn't

Tags: snap.svg

So I have an issue when I start & resize my app window, I'm trying to transform game pieces to move to their new adjusted scaled position, then restart their movement animations.

However, Snap is making the piece's movement animate from a prior position even though I manually moved it to the new location.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem.  If you remove the calls to bounce() and resize the window, the spot is moved instantly to the new size/location as it should be,
but when you put the animation back in, it clearly isn't using this new transform data to interpolate the subsequent animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/furroy/o90neomw/16/

```
var snap;
var c;

$(document).ready(function() {
    snap = new Snap("#screen");
    c = snap.select("#char");
    // i've refactored to make the jsfiddle easier to follow, but the effect is only really noticable 
    // on startup now. you shouldn't see the red dot slide into place - it should just appear there and bounce.
    // the green dot isn't animated and appears in the right place instantly.  the red one is supposed to
    // only have the scale animated, not the move
    positionCharacter();

    // after simplifying the transform, you can't really tell whats going on with the resize now
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        // when you resize the window, the move should be done instantaneously, and the bounce animation
        // from changing the scale should restart at the new location.  you shouldn't see the move animated.
        positionCharacter();
    });
});

// move the character and restart it's bounce() animation in the new location
function positionCharacter()
{
    c.stop();
    c.transform(buildTransform(1.0));    // moving it before animation starts, so you should't see the move happen
    snap.select("#orig").transform(buildTransform(1.0));

    // if you comment out this bounce() you will see that it instantly moves to the correct location on
    // startup and resize before the bounce() starts
    bounce();
}

// animate the scale around a point to create a bounce effect
function bounce()
{
    c.animate({ transform: buildTransform(1.0) }, 250, mina.linear, function() { 
        c.animate({ transform: buildTransform(0.8) }, 250, mina.linear, function() {
            bounce();
        });
    });

}

function buildTransform(vertScale) {
    var t = new Snap.Matrix().translate(100, 100).scale(0.5, 0.5 * vertScale);
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of digging, this seems to break in Snaps equal function. To interpolate attributes it seems to convert them to a string, and in this case it gives an empty attribute to interpolate from (rather than the existing transform matrix).

I'm not sure we usually want to actually animate a matrix anyway, normally what we actually want to do is animate the individual components like rotate, scale etc.

Converting these to Snaps transform string notation, Matrix.toTransformString() gets around this problem. Snap can then animate the individual components.

So adding t = t.toTransformString() makes sense as a reasonable solution.